# In linear algebra, what does completeness mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title says, what does completeness mean in linear algebra?

I found this term when I search for the definition of basis.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)

Comment: In which context you found this word?

Comment: Maybe you mean in *topology* ?

Comment: I found this term when I search for the definition of basis.

Comment: @Matthew if you found the term on that page did you follow the link?

Answer (score 1):

If a vector space has a norm attached to it, you can define [Cauchy sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) in it. A **complete vector space** (also known as a Banach space) is a vector space $V$ in which the limit $v$ of every Cauchy sequence of elements $v_i\in V$ lies in $V$.

The Wikipedia article you link to includes a discussion mentioning that the Hamel basis of an infinite-dimensional complete vector space is uncountable, so I assume this is what you are referring to.